# how to force python call to speedtest.py use secure servers

Tags: python, speed-test

I'm calling speedtest.py from my python program in order to run a speed test.
After importing speedtest.py I create a speedtest object using

```
s = speedtest.Speedtest() 
servers = s.get_best_server()
```

then run upload/download tests.
This has been working, but recently it has been failing.
I found if I just ran speedtest from the cli, I'd get a 403 forbidden error.
I then read than Speedtest now requires the use of secure servers.
SO, if from the cli I type

```
speedtest --secure
```

it runs perfectly.

My question is:
How can I tell speedtest to use secure servers from my python program?

I've tried variations of

```
s = speedtest.Speedtest("secure")
```

and

```
servers = s.get_best_server("secure")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Python API for `speedtest-cli`, but looking at the source, [`Speedtest()` has a `secure` parameter](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/blob/22210ca35228f0bbcef75a7c14587c4ecb875ab4/speedtest.py#L1086-L1090) which presumably makes it require secure servers. So you'd just need to specify it when instantiating the class:

```
s = speedtest.Speedtest(secure=True)
```

---

*BTW, there is [documentation for the Python API](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/wiki#python-api), but it's super barebones and doesn't mention this parameter at all.*